# Brockett cost function on the Stiefel manifold

Tags: matrices, optimization, riemannian-geometry, stiefel-manifolds

In section 4.8 of [Optimization Algorithms on Matrix Manifolds](https://press.princeton.edu/absil) (3rd version), Absil, Mahony & Sepulchre define the cost function
$$ f : \mbox{St} (p,n) \to \mathbb{R}, \qquad X \mapsto \mbox{tr} \left( X^{T} A X N \right)$$ with $N = \mbox{diag} \left(\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_p\right)$ with $0 \leq \mu_1 \leq \ldots \leq \mu_p$.

I would like to play around with this cost function term with explicit matrices. However, I am a bit unsure about this $N$ matrix. How does it look like and what are the $\mu_i$'s?

Before introducing this matrix cost function expression they say that "we now consider a cost function defined as a weighted sum"
$$\sum_{i} \mu_i x^{T}_{(i)} A x_{(i)} $$ of Rayleight quotients on the sphere under and orthogonality constraint, $x^{T}_{i} x_{j}= \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Read carefully the passages before the definition. There must be a description of $A$ and $N$.

Comment: @Laz, thank you for your reply that was extremely useful.

Comment: If you take the square root of $N$, notice that one is weighting the columns of $X$ using the weights $\sqrt{\mu_i}$

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\mathbf{y}_n = \mu_n \mathbf{x}_n$,
$\mathbf{X}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}_1 & \ldots & \mathbf{x}_N
\end{bmatrix}
$
and similarly for $\mathbf{Y}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{y}_1 & \ldots & \mathbf{y}_N
\end{bmatrix}
=\mathbf{XN}$

The cost function writes
$$
\phi
=\sum_n \mathbf{x}_n^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{y}_n
=\mathrm{tr}
\left( \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{Y} \right)
=\mathrm{tr}
\left( \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{XN} \right)
$$